# How to add a circular dot as an indicator in Flutter Tabs?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

We wish to generate the following layout as Scrolling Tabs in Flutter: 
[image]

I tried using `indicator` property of TabBar to customise the indicator to green dot. THE `indicator` property takes a `Decoration` inherited Widget which may have `BoxDecoration`, `ShapeDecoration` and `UnderlineTabDecoration` as options. [image]

Both `BoxDecoration` and `ShapeDecoration` surround the Tab content hence make it difficult to add a circle below the tab. `UnderlineTabDecoration` doesn't provide any methods to round the edges and customize the width.

The best I could come up with was:

```
TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 5.0, ),
          insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:36.0)
        ),

          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(text: 'Week 1',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 2',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 3',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 4',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 5',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 6',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 7',),
            Tab(text: 'Week 8',),

          ],
        ),
```

which results in following look:
[image]

How can I add Circular Dot as an Indicator in Flutter TabBar?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is the question unclear? I took references from https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-12-tabbarview-tabbar-4cdc2112991a and https://mightytechno.com/flutter-boring-tab-to-cool-tab/ for researching about Flutter TabBar Indicators.

Comment: @jaaq I think BLoC pattern and Provider can help in state managment, but what I'm looking out for is to change the styling of the selected Tab in `TabBar`. The default Selected Tab shows an underline, which needs to changed to a circular dot. Check this link for more details: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

as an option

here is an example how to use it, you can bring CircleTabIndicator into your project and modify it as you wish

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title')),
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: TabBar(
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: Colors.green, radius: 4),
            isScrollable: true,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(text: 'Week 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Week 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Week 3'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  CircleTabIndicator({@required Color color, @required double radius}) : _painter = _CirclePainter(color, radius);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _CirclePainter extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;

  _CirclePainter(Color color, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset circleOffset = offset + Offset(cfg.size.width / 2, cfg.size.height - radius);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleOffset, radius, _paint);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works great! Would love to have some resources to learn  how to modify the low level `paint` APIs in Flutter. Would be great if you can share how to customise widgets' properties using low-level Paint methods.

Comment: can anybody please explain, what is going on in this answer? It works really fine but I have not understood the working.

Comment: BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => _painter;
 Getting error onchaged

Comment: @VrustiPatel, The error you are getting is because of null safety. Just change the method signature to:
BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) => _painter;

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need to override anything. You can just give the `tab` a child instead of a text like this:

```
Tab(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Week 6'),
      Icon(Icons.trip_origin, color: Colors.green, size: 1,)
    ],
  ),
),
```

you can change the `Icon` with any widget you want.

Comment: Then, I'll have to build a custom logic to add icon property `onTap` to the selected Widget. I was hoping if the indicator widget itself could be modified since it provides transition animations and tab change logic built in.